# How to configure jsonschema2pojo plugin on gradle kotlin dsl

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm using [jsonschema2pojo](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/tree/master/jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin) gradle plugin in my kotlin dsl [build](https://github.com/rajcspsg/jsonschema2pojo-enum-demo) file.

Now I need to change the default configurations of the plugin as described [here](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/tree/master/jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin#usage)

```
    jsonSchema2Pojo {
      source = files("${sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir}/json")
    }
```

When I add this I get below error -

> $ gradle generateJsonSchema2Pojo
>
> Configure project :
> e: /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/misc/jsonschema2pojo-enum-demo/build.gradle.kts:20:1: Unresolved reference: jsonSchema2Pojo
> e: /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/misc/jsonschema2pojo-enum-demo/build.gradle.kts:21:3: Unresolved reference: source
> e: /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/misc/jsonschema2pojo-enum-demo/build.gradle.kts:21:21: Unresolved reference: sourceSets
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:
>   Build file '/Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/misc/jsonschema2pojo-enum-demo/build.gradle.kts' line: 20
> - What went wrong:
>   Script compilation errors:
>
> Line 20: jsonSchema2Pojo {
> ^ Unresolved reference: jsonSchema2Pojo
>
> Line 21:   source = files("${sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir}/json")
> ^ Unresolved reference: source
>
> Line 21:   source = files("${sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir}/json")
> ^ Unresolved reference: sourceSets
>
> 3 errors

my build file is on github [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/jsonschema2pojo-enum-demo/blob/master/build.gradle.kts).

Any idea how to configure my build file for jsonschema2pojo plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use this kind of configuration in your gradle.build.kts

```
configure <org.jsonschema2pojo.gradle.JsonSchemaExtension> {
    dateTimeType = "java.time.ZonedDateTime"
    includeAdditionalProperties = false
    includeConstructors = true

    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also needed to use `jsonschema2pojo` plugin. For my use case, I've used this kind of configuration (Kotlin DSL):

```
jsonSchema2Pojo {
    source.setFrom("src/main/resources/json")
    targetPackage.set("com.example.generated.pojos")
    sourceType.set("jsonschema")

    // Without kotlin dsl
    // source.setFrom files("${project.rootDir}/src/main/resources/json")
    // targetPackage = 'com.example.generated.pojos'
    // sourceType = 'jsonschema'
}
```

I think that you were interested in `source.setFrom`. I hope this helps.